# FIle downloading using HTTP

Tags: xmpp

I am having trouble finding the correct XEP to use for this specific use case:

Initiator (e.g. iOS or Android device) uploads a file to a server and needs to notify the responder (in this case this would be a browser based client) to download the file from the location he just uploaded to using HTTP.

All the XEP's I have come across talk about streams or IBB/SOCKS5. I did found the following which could be useful but no updates since 2007:

http://xmpp.org/extensions/inbox/jingle-httpft.html

Am I overlooking something on an XEP which is in draft or final?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use [XEP-0066: Out of Band Data](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0066.html), or just encode the link in a [XEP-0071: XHTML-IM](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0071.html) `a` element.

The first:

```
<message from='stpeter@jabber.org/work'
         to='MaineBoy@jabber.org/home'>
  <body>Yeah, but do you have a license to Jabber?</body>
  <x xmlns='jabber:x:oob'>
    <url>http://www.jabber.org/images/psa-license.jpg</url>
  </x>
</message>
```

The second:

```
<message>
  <body>here is a file [http://www.jabber.org/images/psa-license.jpg]</body>
  <html xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im'>
    <body xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
      <p>Here is a <a href='http://www.jabber.org/images/psa-license.jpg'>file</a></p>
    </body>
  </html>
</message>
```